# Aligned and enumerated equations

Tags: align, enumitem

How can I align these equations

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,physics,enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman*)}]
\item $\displaystyle \comm{P_i}{R_k}=\frac{\hbar}{i}\delta_{ik}$
\item $\displaystyle \comm{P^2}{R}=2\frac{\hbar}{i}P$
\item $\displaystyle \comm{P}{R^2}=\frac{2\hbar}{i}R$
\item $\displaystyle \dv{R_{\Psi}}{t}=\frac{1}{m}R_{\Psi}$
\item $\displaystyle \dv{P_{\Psi}}{t}=\qty(-\grad V)_{\Psi}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

in the equal sign?
I am using enumitem and physics package.

Comment: Use the `align` or `align*` environment. Anyway, please add a complete and compilable minimal working example so that we don't have to guess what packages you are using.

Comment: this is not  (very difficult with manual tweaking) possible in `enumitem` environment. possible solution is use `flalign` environment.

Comment: please extend your code snippet to complete small document, from which we can see which package are used or which commands are defined by you.

Comment: I can't see a real reason for aligning those equalities.

Answer (score 2):

You can set elements on the same side `=` in boxes of similar width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem,eqparbox,physics}

\newcommand{\LHS}[2][]{\eqmakebox[#1][r]{$\displaystyle #2$}}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\roman*)}]
  \item $\displaystyle \LHS{\comm{P_i}{\op{R}_k}} = \frac{\hbar}{i} \delta_{ik}$
  \item $\displaystyle \LHS{  \comm{P^2}{\op{R}}} = 2 \frac{\hbar}{i} P$
  \item $\displaystyle \LHS{  \comm{P}{\op{R}^2}} = \frac{2 \hbar}{i} R$
  \item $\displaystyle \LHS{      \dv{R_\Psi}{t}} = \frac{1}{m} R_\Psi$
  \item $\displaystyle \LHS{      \dv{P_\Psi}{t}} = \qty(-\grad V)_\Psi$.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Compile twice with any change in the `\LHS`.

Comment: Is there any way to apply this solution for two different enumerated lists? I try it, but the result is not what one wants

https://gyazo.com/cc101616593c3c731813afa68e20f550

Comment: @Imhotep: Indeed! I wrote `\LHS[<tag>]{<stuff>}` to take an optional `<tag>` argument. Use a different `<tag>` for a different list in order to localise the alignment. Something like `\LHS[first]{..}` for the first list and `\LHS[second]{..}` for the second list.

Comment: Oh, I did not see that. It works. Thank very very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{physics}

%-------------------------------------- only for show page layout
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.25pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\begin{document}
    \begin{flalign*}
\textbf{i)}     &&   \comm{P_i}{\op{R}_k}   & =  \frac{\hbar}{i}\delta_{ik} &\hskip16em   \\
\textbf{ii)}    &&   \comm{P^2}{\op{R}}     & = 2\frac{\hbar}{i}P           &   \\
\textbf{iii)}   &&   \comm{P}{\op{R}^2}     & =  \frac{2\hbar}{i}R          &   \\
\textbf{iv)}    &&   \dv{R_{\Psi}}{t}       & =  \frac{1}{m}R_{\Psi}        &   \\
\textbf{v)}     &&   \dv{P_{\Psi}}{t}       & =  \qty(-\grad V)_{\Psi} .
    \end{flalign*}
or
    \begin{flalign*}
\textbf{i)}     &&   \comm{P_i}{\op{R}_k}   & =  \frac{\hbar}{i}\delta_{ik} &   \\
\textbf{ii)}    &&   \comm{P^2}{\op{R}}     & = 2\frac{\hbar}{i}P           &   \\
\textbf{iii)}   &&   \comm{P}{\op{R}^2}     & =  \frac{2\hbar}{i}R          &   \\
\textbf{iv)}    &&   \dv{R_{\Psi}}{t}       & =  \frac{1}{m}R_{\Psi}        &   \\
\textbf{v)}     &&   \dv{P_{\Psi}}{t}       & =  \qty(-\grad V)_{\Psi} .
    \end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines indicate page layout)